# Issue with using a javascript regular expression as validation pattern in an Angular 2 form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I am trying to use javascript regular expressions as pattern validators from within an Angular 2 template/form.

Here are my JS regexes defined as constants:

```
export class AppConstants {
    static EMAIL_PATTERN = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$/;
    static FIRST_NAME_PATTERN = /^[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ\s'-]+$/;
}
```

I import the regex from the constant within the component:

```
EMAIL_PATTERN = AppConstants.EMAIL_PATTERN;
```

Then within my html:

```
pattern="EMAIL_PATTERN"
```

However, even if the email address is valid, the validator triggers and marks the email field as invalid.

Here is the full template:

```
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon icon-email" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
        <input type="email"
               ngControl="email"
               #email="ngForm"
               required
               pattern="EMAIL_PATTERN"
               [ngModel]="emailInfo.email"
               (ngModelChange)="emailInfo ? emailInfo.email = $event : null"
               placeholder="{{'EMAIL_FORM.NEW_ADDRESS'| translate }}"
               class="form-control"
               validateEmailAvailable/>
        <span *ngIf="isSuccessFeedback(emailForm, email)" class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="glyphicon icon-accept" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
        <span *ngIf="isErrorFeedback(emailForm, email)" class="form-control-feedback" aria-hidden="true">
            <span class="glyphicon icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div [hidden]="email.valid">
        <div *ngIf="email?.errors?.required" class="control-label">{{'EMAIL_FORM.EMAIL_REQUIRED'| translate}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="email?.errors?.pattern" class="control-label">{{'EMAIL_FORM.EMAIL_PATTERN'| translate}}</div>
        <div *ngIf="email?.errors?.unavailable" class="control-label">{{'EMAIL_FORM.ALREADY_IN_USE'| translate}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need

```
[pattern]="EMAIL_PATTERN"
```

to assign the value of `EMAIL_PATTERN` instead of the string `EMAIL_PATTERN`.

<strike>Currently you can't use bindings for `pattern` or other validation rules like `min`, `max`, ... because they need to be static. There is an open issue to support that.</strike>

This was fixed in Angular2 final (from comments)

Comment: Does this work with the validator directives?  The code still has @Attribute(...) injectors, so I thought that it wouldn't receive property values (as it would if it was using @Input injectors).

Comment: Thanks, I'll wait for this feature to be available then.

Comment: The issue related to the use of bindings for pattern has been fixed in Angular 2 Final.

Answer (score 2):

The pattern validator in Angular2 is currently based on the pattern attribute and thus only accepts strings and it follows the semantics of the HTML5 pattern attribute:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern

Your HTML example only accepts a string of "EMAIL_PATTERN" in the input.

If you want to use your variable, I suggest using FormBuilder to define your control.  Otherwise, you'll need to put the actual regex string in the pattern attribute directly.